# Play 3 sprites sequentially without delays

Tags: html5-canvas, sprite, easeljs, createjs, sprite-sheet

I have a big spritesheet and it doesn't fit into one 2048 spritesheet. Hence I splitted it into 3 spritesheets (3 PNGs, 2048x2048)

But in my game it still has to play as a one whole sprite. Here is how I do it:

```
var sprite1 = new createjs.Sprite(ssheet1);
var sprite2 = new createjs.Sprite(ssheet2);
var sprite3 = new createjs.Sprite(ssheet3);

sprite1.on("animationend", sprite1_played);
sprite2.on("animationend", sprite2_played);
sprite3.on("animationend", sprite3_played);

stage.addChild(sprite1, sprite2, sprite3);

... cut here ...

function playSprite()
{
   sprite1.visible = true;
   sprite2.visible = false;
   sprite3.visible = false;

   sprite1.gotoAndPlay("ssh");
}

function sprite1_played()
{
   sprite1.visible = false;
   sprite2.visible = true;
   sprite3.visible = false;

   sprite2.gotoAndPlay("ssh");
}
function sprite2_played()
{
   sprite1.visible = false;
   sprite2.visible = false;
   sprite3.visible = true;

   sprite3.gotoAndPlay("ssh");
}
function sprite3_played()
{
   sprite1.visible = true;
   sprite2.visible = false;
   sprite3.visible = false;

   sprite1.gotoAndPlay("ssh");
}
```

The issue is when I call playSprite() it start playing the sprite combined of 3 different sprites and there is a noticable DELAY between sprite1, 2, 3 playback (on mobile). Delays dissapear on 2nd and all further cycles.

But delays on the first cycle are unaccepted and very annoying.

Do you have any ideas on how to make it run smoothly from the start? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, its worth noting that EaselJS supports multi-image sprite sheets directly. Check out the SpriteSheet documentation for more info.

The delay you are seeing is the cost to load a new large texture (image) to the mobile GPU from memory. You could try forcing the image into graphics memory by having three Bitmaps (or Sprites), one for each image, in the display list but not viewable. You might have to play around with the best way to do this. For example, setting `visible=false` or `alpha=0` will not work, because the elements will just be skipped. Moving them out of bounds might work, or scaling them way

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply, gskinner! I've noticed one interesting thing.. Even if I use visible set to true/false to hide/show each spritesheet it doesn't delay on second cycle. But I set visible property to false and call stop() method. It delays on first cycle only. But if I call playSprite() method again (linked on button click) and it does delay again even though it was playing already... Strange and I couldn't identify the reason yet.